# How to plot two seperate sequences in one plot such that there difference is clear?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, graphing-functions, matlab, python

Suppose I have two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$. They both start from a very high number say $25000$ and converges to zero.

If I plot them in one plot, as they start from a very large number, the plot looks like as if $a_n \approx b_n \approx 0$. But if we look closely, the difference between them is around $2$ or $3$ which is high enough. But since the plot scales itself to accomodate initial numbers, the difference in later iterations just goes away.

So my question is, is there any function $f$, such that if I plot $f(a_n)$ and $f(b_n)$, the difference will be more clear?

I actually care about differences for large $n$. But I cannot miss out on initial iterations as it is required to show that both sequences start from same point.

Comment: Where do you care about the differences - at the start, or when $n$ is large. Consider plotting the difference rather than the values. Maybe plotting the logarithms. Would thinking about the ratio rather than the difference make more sense in your context? We can't help more without more information. You can [edit] the question to provide that.